# Выборка строк из таблицы в SQL-сервере

Tags: sql

Доброго времени суток! 
Необходимо выбрать данные из одной таблицы, но условия выборки находятся в другой: В таблице №1 есть коды устройств и другие поля, которые характеризуют устройства. В таблице №2 есть те же коды устройств и еще одно, другое поле - код заказа, несколько устройств могут относиться к одному заказу. Нужно сделать выборку из таблицы №1 только для тех устройств, которые относятся к одному заказу.

```
    SELECT [Название], [Описание], [Категория] FROM [SofI].[dbo].[СрЗИ] WHERE [Код срзи] = (SELECT [Код срзи] FROM [SofI].[dbo].[Соотвествие] WHERE [Код заказа] = 2)
```

На подобную конструкцию компилятор ругается  "Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения. Это запрещено, когда вложенный запрос следует после =, !=, <, <=, >, >= или используется в качестве выражения."
Я не знаю, как сделать иначе. Прошу помочь мне, если кто-нибудь знает и у вас есть минута свободного времени!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... WHERE [Код срзи] IN (SELECT ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вам, Игорь!